# Ports Listen When Not Actively Executing Script As Admin

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, ssh, port

I have an AWS EC2 Instance:

**I Can:**

Currently SSH into my server and execute a simple command to execute a listener that will reply for each connection to the port

`socat -u tcp-listen:80,fork system:./getmsg.sh`

**getmsg.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
read MESSAGE
echo "PID: $$"
echo "$MESSAGE"
```

However, this seems to not persist when the SSH session ends.

**I'd Like:**

if the EC2 instance would be able to execute the script when I left the SSH session.

**How Can I:**

1. Send information to a port: `nc ServerIP PORT INFORMATION`
2. Execute a script for the data sent through to the server: `?`
3. When I'm not actively connected to the server as an admin/ssh user?

Comment: Use `nohup` to keep a program running when you logout.

Comment: Or use `systemd` to connect the program to the port automatically.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [sf] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Ahh I thought about it - wasn’t sure if the answer would have been a system call/something like nohup/or a programmatic answer. Thought it would be programmatic to be honest. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nohup` to run the process in the background without being killed after logging out.

Another solution would be to use tmux, which allows you to detach sessions.

https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki